# Plotting Seifert surfaces

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to make a Seifert surface in *Mathematica*, such as a Seifert surface for a trefoil knot?

I was thinking of taking the parametrization equations for a trefoil knot and then somehow incorporating a band with it, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any code would be appreciated!

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87220) is related.

Comment: See e.g. https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KnotData.html

Comment: @YvesKlett What about for a figure 8 on a seifert surface?

Comment: Uh, no answer, just wanted to inform you of the existence of `KnotData` to get you a head start (preferably for a self-answer ;-) ). The more detailed your question, the better the chances to get stellar help here, so feel free to edit in code/sample images etc....

Comment: @YvesKlett I used KnotData["FigureEight","SeifertMatrix"] and got the Seifert matrix for a figure 8 to be {1,0},{-1,-1}. I just don't know what to do with that information

Comment: Not sure if the [Seifert matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeifertMatrix.html) will be very helpful in generating the surface. I´d probably start with the `"SpaceCurve"` for a given knot...